# for loop for finding and storing words that is present in supplied word dataset returning name error

Tags: python, list, for-loop, gensim, word2vec

I have a list named `'result'` as below

```
>>> result
    
[
  [
    ['apple'],
    ['banana'],
    ['green','grapes'],
    nan
  ],
  [
    ['orange'],
    ['hat'],
    ['party','hat','2'],
    nan
  ],
  [
    ['blue'],
    ['navy'],
    ['red','t'],
    ['angry']
  ]
]
```

and I'm using gensim to match the words in the pretrained word2vec model with the words I have and get corresponding vectors.

Given that the `pretrained_model.key_to_index` is structured as below…

```
>>> pretrained_model.key_to_index
{'</s>': 0,
     'in': 1,
     'for': 2,
     'that': 3,
     'is': 4,
     'on': 5,
     '##': 6,
     'The': 7,
     'with': 8,
     'said': 9,
     'was': 10,
     'the': 11,
     'at': 12,
    ...}
```

…I used below code to store list of words within 'result' that is present in pretrained model named `'pretrained_model'` and to filter the words that are not in pre trained model.

```py
import gensim

pretrained_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('Downloads/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True) 
    
vocabulary = pretrained_model.key_to_index
        
len(vocabulary)  # =3000000
    
    
documents = []
for x in result:
    document = [i for i in j for j in x if i in pretrained_model.key_to_index]
    documents.append(document)
```

now this `documents` have only those words which are present in pre trained model's vocab.

So the desired output `documents` might look like

```
 [[['apple'],['banana'],['green','grapes']],[['orange'],['hat'],['party','hat']],[['blue'],['navy'],['red','t'],['angry']]]
```

However above code returns NameError as below

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/jd/lh_mnln92n17ysb4p01g000gn/T/ipykernel_2855/2806541.py in <module>
      1 documents = []
      2 for x in result:
----> 3     document = [i for i in j for j in x if i in pretrained_model.key_to_index]
      4     documents.append(document)
      5 #now this document have only those words which are present in our model's vocab

NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Can anyone help on me this please? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `document = [i for j in x for i in j if i in pretrained_model.key_to_index]`

Comment: Just ran the suggested code and it returns TypeError : 'float' object is not iterable... But thank you for your help though

Comment: You have a 3 dimensional list - not sure how you would access items. (Also, not sure about the `nan` items)

Comment: I guess the question was not specific enough so I've edited the post! since the nan values are not in 'pretrained_model.key_to_index', I expect the for loops will drop those nan values and store only the ones that matches with the words within pretrained_model.key_to_index

Comment: "since the nan values are not in 'pretrained_model.key_to_index', I expect the for loops will drop those nan values" It can't do this, because the `nan` values are at the same "level" of the structure as **lists of** strings, and the code is trying to iterate over those `nan`s as if they were lists, giving the error shown.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your `result` structure seems a bit weird. (I've manually added 'pretty-print'-like indentation to make its nesting levels clearer.)

It's hard to imagine sensible reasons for so many 1-word lists, and mixing `nan` values (tricky pseudo-numbers) into *some* but not *all* ending-slots of the 2nd-level lists. It's possible you've got a good reason, but it's odd enough to imply that some earlier steps, that created that `result` list-of-lists-and-nans`, may not have been clearly thought-out.

So I'd mainly suggest going back to your previous step, and trying to have a working structure that's:

1. *less-nested* – because tricky nesting & positionally-implied-interpretations are always tricky, especially if you're a beginner; and…
2. doesn't result in any less-easy-to-handle data types like `nan` mixed in at the same levels as would otherwise be lists (or strings).  (Dealing with `nan` values should be very rare in beginner code that isn't specifically designed to do math on low-quality inputs.)

But if you did need to do what you're explicitly asking – walking through a 3-level-nested structure, dropping some elements, you'd need some fancier looping structures.

And further, you can't blindly try to treat `nan` values as if they're the same `list` objects (and thus iterable) as their sibling-level list elements. You'd need to add a test to only iterate over things that are iterable.

(If after integrating all the comment suggestions & this answer, you're still needing to do the same thing, I'd suggest posting a focused new question on exactly where your latest & best attempt is failing, and with what error.)